# How to fix 'mixed content' error for S3 website with Flask backend API

Tags: angular, flask, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pythonanywhere

In short: I have been unable to make the necessary changes to my website so it will stop saying 'not secure' in the browser. My first step was to generate a certificate to run https for my s3 with amazon certificate manager. I was able to connect the certificate to my domain successfully. However, once I did that, all my https calls from my angular frontend to my flask api hosted in pythonanywhere failed, and I'm getting a 'mixed content' error. At this point I assume it won't work until I make the necessary changes to the flask api so that the browser deems it sufficiently secure. I am not sure what I need to do to accomplish the last step.

For context, here's the full stack / services I'm using for my website:

- Angular frontend hosted in an S3 as a static website
- Cloudfront managing requests to s3, redirecting http to https
- Route 53 to manage custom domain I bought with google domains
- Flask backend api hosted on pythonanywhere
- mysql database included in pythonanywhere

My angular frontend has one service that makes a number of separate calls to the flask api. They look like this: **this.https.get('http://###.pythonanywhere.com/###', {headers})**. After I added the https certificate to my domain and then started up a cloudfront distribution to redirect http to https for my website, all these api calls to the backend failed with this message: **'Mixed Content: The page at 'https://###.report/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://###.pythonanywhere.com/###'**.

**Here are the steps I've taken to make my flask api on pythonanywhere more secure**:

I updated my cors policy in app.py like this: **cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "https://###.report"}})**.

I added these headers to the requests:

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://###.report')
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization')
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
return response

I enabled the 'Force HTTPS' setting on pythonanywhere for my flask app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
this.https.get('http://###.pythonanywhere.com/###', {headers})
```

to

```
this.https.get('https://###.pythonanywhere.com/###', {headers})
```